# Indexing into a list using a sorting function on strings

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I have an existing list of strings that I am reading from a CSV which follow a naming convention, for example...

```
["",
"00000-ABC-XX-00-DR-A-20100",
"00000-ABC-XX-01-DR-A-20101",
"00000-ABC-XX-02-DR-A-20102",
"",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20350",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20351",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20352",
""]
```

Given a list of new strings not yet in the list, I want to know what index in the list they would be placed if inserted in a way which retains the sequential numbering. As if they were organised by list.sort().

The reason I cannot use list.sort is that it will segregate all of the empty string values that represent a row gap in the CSV into one group and the sorted strings after this.

For example, If I wanted to insert the following 2 values...

```
["00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20300","00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20301"]
```

The existing list would now look like this...

```
["",
"00000-ABC-XX-00-DR-A-20100",
"00000-ABC-XX-01-DR-A-20101",
"00000-ABC-XX-02-DR-A-20102",
"",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20300",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20301",
"",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20350",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20351",
"00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20352",
""]
```

Is there a smart `list.sorted` parameter that would return the indices of these 2 new rows or do I need to write a function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to sort again to find an index from a sorted list.

Comment: You can do a `sort` with `data.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda a, b: 0 if not a or not b else 1 if a > b else -1 if a < b else 0))` to treat empty strings as equal to any adjacent string, but then groups of numeric strings on opposite sides of empty strings won't necessarily get sorted correctly relative to each other.

Comment: Just my two cents, but I feel like maintaining the row gaps in your list is just going to make your life harder. The CSV data doesn't have a way to represent groupings of data other than that, but in the python world you certainly do - maybe consider lists of lists, or something to that effect? It's hard to say specifically without knowing what the row gaps are meant to represent, but you can retain that information without having to code around it in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bisect` with a `key` function will find you the insertion point:

```
from bisect import bisect
from functools import cmp_to_key

data = [
    "",
    "00000-ABC-XX-00-DR-A-20100",
    "00000-ABC-XX-01-DR-A-20101",
    "00000-ABC-XX-02-DR-A-20102",
    "",
    "00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20350",
    "00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20351",
    "00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20352",
    "",
]

key_func = cmp_to_key(
    lambda a, b: 0 if not a or not b else 1 if a > b else -1 if a < b else 0
)
for val in ["00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20300","00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20301"]:
    data.insert(bisect(data, key_func(val), key=key_func), val)

print(*data, sep="\n")
```

```
00000-ABC-XX-00-DR-A-20100
00000-ABC-XX-01-DR-A-20101
00000-ABC-XX-02-DR-A-20102

00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20300
00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20301
00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20350
00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20351
00000-ABC-XX-ZZ-DR-A-20352
```

Note that finding the insertion point for the two new strings does not it itself insert a *new* empty string in between the non-sequential numbers, as in your example.